# Prototype conversion stuck

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypejs

Hey guys im not very good with both jquery or Prototype so i started to convert the parts I know, so could you please do the rest and thanks guys

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var offsetLeft=$('menu').offsetLeft;
    Event.observe('menu', 'mousemove', function(event){

        coordinateX=Event.pointerX(event)-offsetLeft;
        $('slider').style.marginLeft=coordinateX-20+'px';

    });

});
```

question:
can you help me with the conversion to jquery

Comment: Have you tried doing anything yourself yet?

Comment: yes I did which was the $(document).ready(function() part

Comment: I don't have any clue about prototype nor what you are trying to do with the scrip, but I guess what will get you started is: http://api.jquery.com/css/ and http://api.jquery.com/mousemove

Comment: i got it down to this ------------------------------------------------$(document).ready(function(){
 var val = document.pointform.form_x.value();
  var off = ('#menu').offset.left;
     val1 = val.offset.left;
  
  
  
 $("#menu").mousemove(function(event) {
  var coordinateX = (val - off);
    $('#slider').css('margin-left',  coordinateX - 20+'px');
  
 });
 
});

Comment: If you set up sth like a jsfiddle.net and describe what you are trying to do and what is not working someone might be able to help you. This way I cannot even read the code without getting a headache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Direct translation would be:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var offsetLeft = $('#menu').offset().left;
    $('#menu').bind('mousemove', function(event) {
        var coordinateX = event.pageX - offsetLeft;
        $('#slider').css("margin-left", (coordinateX - 20) + 'px');
    });
});
```

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/6D5qH/).

However, you better read the documentation and understand how things work so that you can do those things on your own in the future.